# `ERR` trap is not executed when syntax error

Tags: bash, bash-trap

According to `man bash`,

> `set -e`
>
> Exit immediately if (snip). A trap on `ERR`, if set, is executed before the shell exits.

However, the script below doesn't invoke the `ERR` trap.

```
trap 'echo ERR; sleep 1' ERR
trap 'echo EXIT; sleep 1' EXIT

set -e

array=(a b c)
echo $(( ${#array[@] - 1)) #note the closing bracket } is forgotten

echo "after"
```

The expected result is

```
$ bash script.sh 
4.sh: line 7:  ${#array[@] - 1: bad substitution
ERR
EXIT
# and then shell exits
```

The actual result is

```
$ bash script.sh 
4.sh: line 7:  ${#array[@] - 1: bad substitution
EXIT
# and then shell exits
```

If I delete the line `set -e`, then

```
$ bash script2.sh
4.sh: line 7:  ${#array[@] - 1: bad substitution
after #the last echo command is executed
EXIT
```

This means `set -e` catches the syntax error. Why isn't the `ERR` trap invoked although the shell **does** exit?

---

Environment:

I tested the script on two machines.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

---

Supplement:

According to the posted answers, it is natural the trap isn't executed and this is because `echo $(( ${#array[@] - 1))` doesn't complete its execution to return exit status. Is my understanding right?

However, `man bash` explains `set -e` as

> Exit  immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a  non-zero status.

I think this also requires the command to complete. If `echo $(( ${#array[@] - 1))` doesn't complete its execution, I believe `set -e` should not work here and `echo "after"` should be executed.

---

Supplement2:

According to [oguz ismail's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317346/err-trap-is-not-executed-when-syntax-error#comment102997458_58318623), this is a documentation issue. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) says `set -e` shall exit the shell when

- non-zero exit status is returned (as you can see in `man bash`)
- **or** *shell error* occurs

and [shell error includes syntax error](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01). But `man bash` is missing the explanation for the second case, right? If so, everything is consistent other than the fact that `man bash` doesn't explain the implementation accurately and the statement "These are the same conditions obeyed by the `errexit` (`-e`) option." found in the `trap`'s explanation in `man bash`.

Comment: I believe the question is on topic here, however you might want to also post on the [Unix&Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) where you might have more chance to get an answer quickly.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for your advice. I'll consider it if there is no good answer posted.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point that `ERR` tests return codes from *completed* commands, not from commands that have not been executed (how can it?).  What you are observing is correct and expected behaviour.

Comment: @cdarke Ok, I understand it. But then why does `set -e` catch the syntax error? `man bash` doesn't say it catches syntax errors. (POSIX says so (see Suppliment2 in OP), but `bash` isn't POSIX compliant.)

Comment: Looking at the source code, the `set -e` (`errexit`) and `traps ERR` use different code and mechanisms to test and action errors.  The `set -e` exits immediately, the `ERR` trap only tests when a command is run, that's why the `set -e` catches the syntax error and the `ERR` trap does not.   `man bash` implies that the two mechanisms act in the same way, but clearly they don't and they never have.

Comment: Agree with @cdarke completely. If you are not convinced still on be answers, try upping it with a bounty and see if you can attract more comprehensive answers

Comment: @cdarke "man bash implies that the two mechanisms act in the same way, but clearly they don't and they never have." How clearly? From the source code? I don't think that is clear. Rather, the behavior contradicts with `man bash`. Normal users expect any behaviors not from the source code but from `man bash`, I believe. In other words, `man bash` is all from the perspective of users (non-bash-developer). (I admit the fact that the two commands act differently, but my original question is "why so?" as explicitly written in OP. Because of `man bash`'s bug? Because I miss something in `man bash`?)

Comment: If cdarke says "*man bash implies that the two mechanisms act in the same way*" and Inian says "*Agree with cdarke completely.*", I don't understand why they cited `man bash` in their answers. They think `man bash` is incomplete, but cite it to answer my question? It seems their answers should be something like "It is a bug of `man bash`. Instead see the source code." to be logically consistent.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of a weird way how `set -e` is implemented in `bash` over the years. It comes around with lot of specific cases under which is expected to work.

From `man bash`:

- `trap ... ERR`

  - If a sigspec is *ERR*, the command *arg* is executed whenever a pipeline *(which may consist of a single simple command)*, a list, or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status, subject to the following  conditions:

    - The *ERR* trap is not executed if the failed command is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword...
    - ...part of the test in an `if` statement...
    - ...part of a command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`...
    - ...any command in a pipeline but the last...
    - ...or if the command's return value is being inverted using `!`.
  - These  are  the  same conditions obeyed by the *errexit* `-e` option.

What you have in this example code is a [shell expansion error](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06) for which the above mentioned clauses *never* really apply. In all the above clauses an incorrect command runs/completes and *sets* an return-code back to the shell for your `ERR` trap to fire.

But when the line `echo $(( ${#array[@] - 1))` is encountered, soon after the arithmetic expansion fails, there is no command that is actually run that would fire an `ERR` trap, because to fire a trap the command needs to be complete. From the `man bash` page

- If `Bash` is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes.

Comment: Actually the `ERR` trap was implemented originally in korn shell, and bash just emulated that behaviour.

Comment: Please see my suppliment in OP.

Answer (score 1):

The `ERR` trap has never trapped syntax errors, and is not designed for that.  From `man bash`:

```
  If  a  sigspec  is  ERR,  the command arg is executed whenever a
  pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list,
  or a compound command returns a non-zero exit status ...
```

in this case the command is never executed, so does not return a non-zero status, the script fails before that.

Comment: `man bash` says `If a sigspec is ERR, the command ard is executed whenever ... These are the same conditions obeyed by the errexit (-e) option.` In my case, `set -e` catches the syntax error, so if `trap <command> ERR` works on the same condition as `set -e`, the `ERR` trap should be executed, I believe.

Comment: @ynn But it doesn't work on the same condition as `set -e`, that's the point!  The `ERR` trap invoked *after* the command is executed, in this case the command is never executed.

Comment: But `man bash` also says in the section of `set -e` command that `Exit  immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a  non-zero status.` So if your interpretation is right, the shell should never exit (`echo "after"` should be executed). But, in my case, the shell exits for some reason.

Comment: @ynn: You are missing the excerpt for `trap` in the man page. The trap won't be fired until a command completes, but the line with the syntax error never gets to complete

Comment: @ynn the standard says *-e When this option is on, when any command fails (for any of the reasons listed in Section 2.8.1, Consequences  of  Shell Errors or by returning an exit status greater than zero), the shell immediately shall exit*, so it's just a documentation issue

Comment: Please see my suppliment in OP.